# TailwindCSS enforce light mode for specific component when using "media" config

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Currently working on a latest nextjs project using tailwind. In my tailwind.config.js I have `darkMode: "media",` set and every component is implemented that way. On a specific page I need to enforce light mode in such a way that also the components used on that page know that. Any ideas?

Comment: Override all `dark:` classes on that page by deleting them or via props.

Comment: From memory ```darkMode: "media"``` makes use of ```prefers-color-scheme```. Which is the browser preference. Looking at the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) your best bet might be to transition to the "selector" strategy. This will let you force a light mode where necessary and with the addition of some JS you can still default to the browser preference - emulating ```prefers-color-scheme```

Comment: I thought about that, but then it is difficult to get a smooth transition when the system switches between themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#overriding-the-dark-variant) strategy

> If you’d like to replace Tailwind’s built-in dark variant with your own custom variant, you can do so using the variant dark mode strategy:

In this case I'm using user browser preferences but if element contains `enforced` class dark mode will not be applied

```js
export default {
  darkMode: ['variant', '@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { &:not(.enforced) }'],
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="dark:text-red-500">Red</div>

  <div class="enforced dark:text-red-500">Not red</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/HoqnSZg9AH) (Switch to dark mode)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I modified it a little bit to be more flexible:
`darkMode: ['variant', ['@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { &:not(.light *) }', '&:is(.dark *)']]`
Now I can simple add `light` and `dark` class to force specific themes.